# calculating date difference while in Loop

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I have an array of objects where I am looping through to display data in the HTML using `*ngFor`. Each object also contains 2 dates , start and end.

How can I perform a calculation of the difference and display it in months / years on each object that being looped ?

what is the best way in this case to achieve this ! thanx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get difference between 2 dates in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">{{getDiffDate(item.dateStart, item.dateEnd)}}</div>

getDiffDate(dateStart:Date, dateEnd:Date){
   return dateEnd.getTime() - dateStart.getTime() //result in miliseconds. Just convert it to whatever you want
}
```

Comment: `1day = 24h = 24*60m = 24*60*60s = 24*60*60*1000ms`. Now you are having number of ms.